# Using Excel for Frequency

Tags: probability

A box contains 9 yellow balls and 4 green balls. The experiment is to draw two balls from the box, with the ball being replaced after each draw. The color of both balls are recorded. Repeat the experiment the number of times as indicated in the tables.
Number of Draws: 800
Sample Space: Both G, Both Y, One Each
Find: Probability, Relative Probability

I do not know what formulas to use in Excel to set this up.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question alternately on StackOverflow as well, a forum for programmers. You will get more relevant help there if not here.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try!

Answer (score 1):

The Excel function rand() returns a Uniform(0,1) pseudo-random number.  So the formula

=IF(rand()<9/13,"Y","G")

will generate a "Y" with probability 9/13 and a "G" with probability 4/13.  If you enter that formula into columns A and B, rows 1 through 800 of a spreadsheet, you will have simulated two draws with replacement, repeated 800 times.  (Obviously, you would use copy/paste to do this, rather than typing in the formula 1600 times.)  I guess you can figure out how to tally the various combinations of outcomes for yourself, but if not, let us know.